# Is it legal to Interrupt() a Z3 context that is idle?

Tags: .net, z3

Is it legal to call `Interrupt` on a Z3 `Context` with the managed API when that context is idle (i.e. no solvers are running)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The following code succeeds:

```
var context = new Context();
context.Interrupt();
```